# python change big money into smaller money

Tags: python-3.x

okay so i have a code that can change big money into smaller money like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

money = int(input("input your money "))
m1 = 0
t5 = 0
t10 = 0

# split biggger money into smaller one
while money >= 10:
    money = money - 10000
    m10 = m10 + 1
while money >= 5:
    money = money - 5000
    m5 = m5 + 1
while money >= 1:
    money = money - 1000
    m1 = m1 + 1

# print them out
if m10$ > 0:
    print("there are %i 10$" % t10k)
if m5$ > 0:
    print("there are %i 5$" % t5k)
if m1$ > 0:
    print("there are %i 1$" % t1k)
```

so is there anyway make this code shorter

Comment: (`big money` - [A billion here, a billion there, pretty soon, you're talking real money](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Everett_Dirksen#Misattributed))

Comment: `is there anyway make this code shorter` well, there are groups of three (number of denominations) similar statements, which suggests another level of looping. Then, repeated subtraction has a mathematical abstraction, even an operator in most programming languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is there anyway make [the code from the question shorter?]`
or even correct (incomplete conversion from perl?)
With `denominations` a sequence of natural numbers ending with `1`, the following should work; reasonably so if decreasing in value:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

money = int(input("input the amount "))
denominations = (100, 30, 10, 3, 1)

for denomination in denominations:
    count, money = divmod(money, denomination)
    if count:
        print("there are", count, denomination, "radolls")
```